# How to fill cell using if else with cell color as the basis

Tags: excel

One final obstacle on my project is the IF condition based on cell color fill.

(Note: I tried searching for an answer but the only one that fits my scenario is too advanced and lacked the basic instruction that will help me apply it on my own).

For a quick insight into what I'm trying to do, here's a screenshot:

[image]

**What I'm hoping to achieve is:**

if `E4` has a `yellow color fill`, then fill `G4` with "haha"

else, fill it with "hehe"

The screenshot sample currently have no formula in column G, just the sample of what I want to achieve. How can I finish this?

Comment: I'd research an UDF based on the [Interior.Color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.color) property.

Comment: I'd look it up now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The only way to check fill color is with VBA. If those filled cells are filled based on a condition, maybe you should do something like *If thiscell meets conditions to be filled then adyacent one = "haha"*

Comment: Why is the first cell in yellow to begin with? Is this a configuration or the result of conditional formatting? In the latter case, you might base your solution on that condition.

Comment: Thank you everyone, all your help are appreciated. For now, while I'm still learning, I decided to add a new column and put a word "multi" if it's yellow. I do this by sorting/filtering by color. Then I base my new if else on that word "multi"

Comment: @Dominique, indeed it is conditional formatting made by someone in my team. I'd ask about it and see what we can do.

Comment: @TheAuthor: as it is conditional formatting, you can not rely on the formatting: imagine that you base some action on the colour and the author of the conditional formatting decides to change the colour, then your action is not executed anymore. Therefore you need to base your action on the condition, as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: I really appreciate you trying to help @Dominique. However for this specific tool, it will always be same yellow color. And what I'm really looking for is how to make it possible to use color as a basis for IF ELSE formula. I need to grasp the concept and apply it with much more specific rules.